# aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo called twice for single failed login

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm using the SqlMembershipProvider and have a problem where aspnet_Membership_UpdateUserInfo is being called twice for a single failed logon. This means that a user will be locked out after only two attempts, not the 3 that I have configured.

Unfortunately I can't simply bump the login attempts count to a higher number as the problem only seems to be happening for IE users. Firefox and Chrome don't exibit the same problem.

The config I'm using is:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AcademyWebProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="3">
    <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" />
        <add minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
            minRequiredPasswordLength="3" 
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" 
            passwordAttemptWindow="15" 
            applicationName="AcademyPro" 
            connectionStringName="SqlServer" 
            enablePasswordReset="true" 
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
            name="AcademyWebProvider" 
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

**UPDATE**
Digging around a bit more and looking at the fiddler traces IE7 (IE7 proper, not IE 8 computability mode) and IE8 submit the form twice. I also added `onsubmit="alert('Ping!');"` to the form tag, the alert box shows twice, so what ever the problem is it's in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was to do with the CSS Adapters, remove them and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If it's IE8 specifically that the problem is occuring in then try using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to look at the requests that are being sent to your server, to see if multiple requests are being submitted by the browser.

It could be that the bugs in [IE8's Lookahead Downloader](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/Bugs-in-the-IE8-Lookahead-Downloader.aspx) have something to do with it.

Comment: Using fiddler it looks like IE8 is sending all login requests twice. Both valid and invalid, it makes me wonder what else gets sent twice.

Comment: @ilivewithian Have you tried in IE7 to see if it occurs there or is specific to IE8, if it is, then the Lookahead Downloader might be a good candidate? Or a misbehaving add-in... (IE7 Virtual Image: http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)